# Online CDN, and background color control, for this three.js examle?

Tags: three.js, vrml

This could be a continuation of [What is the URL for three.js to include it online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434732/what-is-the-url-for-three-js-to-include-it-online) , I guess...

I had found this example online:

- https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/chapter-08/16-load-vrml.html

To have it run from a single file (included below), so it downloads all its JS libs online, I've had to change this part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/VRMLLoader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/stats.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/dat.gui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Into this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/VRMLLoader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Question 1: Is there a more appropriate CDN for `VRMLLoader.js` and similar libraries, so this example runs from a single .html file? I'd rather not hit `three.js` - then again, if I enter a fake link like https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.js I get a 404 with "Read the full documentation for more information about using GitHub Pages.", so maybe it's OK now?

Anyways, when I run the file in Firefox 57.0.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, I get this:

[image: three.js]

As you can see, the background is fluorescent green, likely RGB of 0x00FF00; however, the code says:

```
    webGLRenderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x000, 1.0));
```

... so I should get a black background here, instead? And if I set `0xFFF` instead of `0x000` in `.setClearColor`, then I get a yellow background ?!

Question 2: How can I specify a background color, and have it render correctly, in this three.js example?

Here is the file `threejs-16-load-vrml.html` - just save it locally and open in a browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!-- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/master/chapter-08/16-load-vrml.html
 -->

<html>

<head>
    <title>Example 08.16 - Load vrml model </title>

<!--     <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/VRMLLoader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/stats.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/dat.gui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
 -->
<!--     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.js"></script>
 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/VRMLLoader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to go fullscreen */
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Stats-output">
</div>
<!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
<div id="WebGL-output">
</div>

<!-- Javascript code that runs our Three.js examples -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    // once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
    function init() {

        var stats = initStats();


        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        // create a render and set the size
        var webGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        webGLRenderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xFFF, 1.0));
        webGLRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        webGLRenderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = 30;
        camera.position.y = 30;
        camera.position.z = 30;
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

        var orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

        var dir1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0.4);
        dir1.position.set(-30, 30, -30);
        scene.add(dir1);

        var dir2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0.4);
        dir2.position.set(-30, 30, 30);
        scene.add(dir2);

        var dir3 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0.4);
        dir3.position.set(30, 30, -30);
        scene.add(dir3);

        // add spotlight for the shadows
        var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
        spotLight.position.set(30, 30, 30);
        scene.add(spotLight);

        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(webGLRenderer.domElement);

        // call the render function
        var step = 0;


        // setup the control gui
        var controls = new function () {
            // we need the first child, since it's a multimaterial


        };

        var group;
        var gui = new dat.GUI();


        var loader = new THREE.VRMLLoader();
        var group = new THREE.Object3D();
//~         loader.load("../assets/models/vrml/tree.wrl", function (model) {
        loader.load("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/master/assets/models/vrml/tree.wrl", function (model) {

            console.log(model);

            model.traverse(function (child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
//                    child.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xaaaaaa});
                    console.log(child.geometry);
                }
            });

            model.scale.set(10, 10, 10);

            scene.add(model);

        });


        render();


        function render() {
            stats.update();

            orbit.update();

            if (group) {
                group.rotation.y += 0.006;
                // group.rotation.x+=0.006;
            }

            // render using requestAnimationFrame
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        function initStats() {

            var stats = new Stats();
            stats.setMode(0); // 0: fps, 1: ms

            // Align top-left
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

            document.getElementById("Stats-output").appendChild(stats.domElement);

            return stats;
        }
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `dat.gui.js` should be [`dat.gui.min.js`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

1. `dat.gui.js` -> `dat.gui.min.js`
2. Read attentively about `THREE.Color()` [here](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Color).

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor('#fff');
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "blue", wireframe: true}));
scene.add(sphere);

var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(sphere.scale, "x", .5, 2);

render();
function render(){
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: "`dat.gui.js` -> `dat.gui.min.js`" This is tantalizingly terse. What do you mean? The OP should change dat.gui.js to dat.gui.min.js everywhere? He already made that change twice. Oh, maybe you mean in the "fake link like https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.js"?

Comment: @LarsH Yes. This is the answer for your last question.